# My code is not running because of abrupt core dump(segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, segmentation-fault, coredump

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void converter(vector<char>keypad[],int num[], int index, string result, int size_of_num){
   if(index == size_of_num){
    cout << result << " ";
   return;
   }

  int digit = num[index];
  int size_of_keypad = keypad[digit].size();

  for(int i=0; i < size_of_keypad; i++){
    converter(keypad, num, index + 1, result + keypad[digit][i], size_of_num);
  }
  
}


int main(){
    vector <char> keypad[] = {
    {},{},{'a','b','c'},
        {'d','e','f'},
        {'g','h','i'},
        {'j','k','l'},
        {'m','n','o'},
        {'p','q','r','s'},
        {'t','u','v'},
        {'w','x','y','z'}};

    int numbers[] = {2,3,4};

    int size_of_num = sizeof(numbers);
    
    converter(keypad, numbers, 0, string (""), size_of_num );

    return 0;
}
```

I tried running this code, which was to transfrom phone numbers into words. I used vector in this problem with a reucrsive function. But I am not sure if its just the memory overflowing or just totally something else.

I tried and search online in order to solve this and I found the correct code, but everything they were doing was the same and the only thing that was differnt were the varible names. I just couldn't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: You are mixing up "C" style arrays with C++ vectors that isn't good.  Vectors can be nested so if you want 2D data use `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`  or `std::vector<std::string>`. But to convert a character to an int, use std::unordered_map<char,int>

Comment: A vector of strings would be an easier data structure to use than an array of char vectors. `vector<string> keypad = { "", "", "abc", "def" ... };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you calculate size wrong

```
int size_of_num = sizeof(numbers);
```

should be

```
int size_of_num = sizeof(numbers)/ sizeof(numbers[0])
```

or even

```
int size_of_num = std::size(numbers);
```